# WiFi Won't Reliably Connect On Ubuntu Server Bootup/Reboot

Tags: wireless, server

I am using Ubuntu Server `14.04.2 LTS` and the micro wireless adapter `TP-LINK TL-WN725N`.

I am having trouble with automatic connection when booting up. If I reboot 10 times, it may only connect 4-6 times. When it fails, I can always get it to connect with:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

`lsusb` output:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6377 Alcor Micro Corp. Multimedia Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`dmesg` before restarting network:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ dmesg
[   16.105721] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   16.801211] R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc
[   17.145207] init: failsafe main process (651) killed by TERM signal
[   17.524498] init: network-manager main process (767) terminated with status 127
[   17.524520] init: network-manager main process ended, respawning
[   19.066032] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
```

`interfaces` file:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid the-ssid
wpa-psk the-pw
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

`ifup` output that successfully connects:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo ifup wlan0
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

UPDATE:
Additional, hopefully helpful info:

I ran `wpa_cli -i wlan0 status` and it returns `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname wlan0 error: Permission denied`.

I looked at `/var/log/upstart/network-interface-wlan0.log` and it shows `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0 error: Read-only file system`.

`dmesg` after `sudo apt-get purge network-manager`:

```
[   14.539832] R8188EU: Firmware Version 11, SubVersion 1, Signature 0x88e1
[   14.660066] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
[   14.660083] work still pending
[   14.916594] MAC Address = e8:de:27:a3:e7:f6
[   14.921775] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   14.921802] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   14.921806] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   14.921809] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   14.921814] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.921817] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.921821] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.921824] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   14.921828] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   16.233140] R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc
```

UPDATE 2: Results of `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0`:

```
Configuring interface wlan0=wlan0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -C /var/run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
wpa_supplicant: configuring network block -- 0
wpa_supplicant: wpa-ssid "the-ssid" -- OK
wpa_supplicant: wpa-psk ***** -- OK
wpa_supplicant: enabling network block 0 -- OK
ip addr add 192.168.1.150/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255           dev wlan0 label wlan0
ip link set dev wlan0   up
 ip route add default via 192.168.1.1  dev wlan0
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

Comment: I decided to just use eth0, so any new answers I will be unable to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

Make sure that these attributes are identical:

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Save the file and restart network manager as follows:

```
sudo service networkmanager restart
sudo service network restart
```

Use the following command if you want a specific adapter to be used and not the whole network manager to start

```
sudo ifconfig
```

For wireless connection use

```
sudo iwconfig
```

To get a list of all the adapters that you have on your machine with their names

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

You can replace `wlan0` with the adapter name that you have on your machine in case you have wireless connection.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

You can replace `eth0` with the adapter name that you have on your machine in case you have wired connection.

Comment: I don't have NetworkManager installed.

Comment: This implies that you actually do: `init: network-manager main process (767) terminated with status 127` I suggest you do: `sudo apt-get purge network-manager` and reboot. Are the symptoms the same?

Comment: @chili555 I am testing now and will let you know soon, but this was happening before I installed/uninstalled network-manager so I could use `nm-tool`.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but found it online and I tried running `wpa_cli -i wlan0 status` and it returns `Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname wlan0  error: Permission denied`.

Comment: @chili555 After purging and rebooting, still no access on bootup.

Comment: What does `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0` tell us?

Comment: I added output to the bottom of my question

Comment: If you get permission denied, then you have a problem with credentials of the wireless network you are connecting to, and please be sure to use the sudo privilege before running all of your commands. You much check your SSID and Network Key, and if you cannot still connect to them, restart the network manager and if not, restart the machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is same Realtek driver problem. You can install a good driver with fixes. Run

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot.

Comment: Looked promising after 2 boots, but 3rd one failed, same issue.